# How to call a function in parent class PHP?

Tags: php, class, function

I have two PHP classes. The first one is like :

```
<?php 
     $myclass = new MainClass;

     class MainClass{
              public $login;

              public function __construct(){
                  require_once('login.class.php');
                  $this->login = new login;
              }

              public function mysql(){
                  mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
              }   


     }
?>
```

And my Login class is :

```
<?php

   class Login{

           public function checkDB(){
               //**** how do I call mysql on MainClass here ?*****
          }
    }
?>
```

I need to mention that Login is Not child class of Main Class. So **I'm wondering how to call `mysql` function on MainClass from Login Class ?**

Comment: $mc = new MainClass(); $mc->mysql();  in your login function.  But this isn't the right way to go about that.  You want a db class that returns the database handler which you can reuse.

Comment: You have no *parent* class here, because there is no inheritance. The word "parent" has a specific meaning in terms of object-oriented programming and classes; it is the class from which another class inherits. You should remove the word "parent" from your title, it is currently very misleading.

Answer (score 2):

**Method1:** : Derived class,

```
<?php
require_once('MainClass.php'); // MainClass store as a php file
   class Login extends MainClass{

           public function checkDB(){
               $this->mysql(); //**** call mysql from MainClass here
          }
    }
?>
```

**Method2:** : Object instance,

```
<?php
require_once('MainClass.php'); // MainClass store as a php file
$check_mysql = new MainClass();

   class Login extends MainClass{

           public function checkDB(){
               $check_mysql->mysql(); //**** call mysql from MainClass here
          }
    }
?>
```

**Note:** Don't use MySQL functions because they are deprecated, so use `mysqli` or `PDO` for connecting DB.

Answer (score 1):

use this code, you just have to create object of `MainClass` and call the mainClass function.

```
<?php

class Login{

       public function checkDB(){
           $main = new MainClass();
           $main->mysql();
      }
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm already initiating the MainClass in 'MainClass' class php. Is that alright to initiate same class two times ?

Comment: @user1725155 yes its alright to initiate same class two times.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an object-oriented handler for this, instead of reinventing the wheel, use the `mysqli` class. Documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), code example below:

```
class Login extends mysqli {
  public function __construct($loginid) {
    $this->id = $loginid; // example of wrapping
    parent::__construct( /* login constants go here */ );
  }
  . . .
  // other functions that can have direct access to the mysqli:: class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As shapeshifter said in the comments, you want a class that you can reference from other classes. Instead, I would probably do something like this:

```
<?php
$database = new MainClass();
class Login
{
   public function checkDB($database)
   {
       $database->mysql();
   }
}
?>
```